# validate search parameters on Google search appliance

Tags: google-search-appliance

On all our websites, we have implemented GSA for search functionality. Recently, the search term has been scanned for cross site scripting vulnerability. I know we can use JavaScript to validate the search term before sending the query to GSA. But I am not sure how many places, we need to implement this.

Is there a way we can do this directly on GSA?

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the OWASP guidelines for XSS prevention.
As a rule of thumb, never output content on the page that hasn't been encoded.

https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet